# Post-Composition By Diffeomorphism And Integrability

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, differential-geometry, change-of-variable, bochner-spaces

Let $d,D$ be positive integers, $p \in [1,\infty)$, $U$ an (non-empty) open subset of $\mathbb{R}^D$, and suppose that $f$ is:

- In the [Bochner-Lebesgue space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral) $L^p_{\mu}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d);\mathbb{R}^D)$, where $\mu$ is a [Radon measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_measure) on $\mathbb{R}^D$ and $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^d$
- The $\mu$-[essential support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)#Essential_support) of $f$ is in $U$.

Let $\phi$ be an auto-diffeomorphism of $U$.  Is it true that 
$$
f \in L^p_{\mu}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d);\mathbb{R}^D)
 \Leftrightarrow
\phi\circ f L^p_{\mu}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d);\mathbb{R}^D)?
$$
*Thoughts/Comments:*

- The answer can be worked out in the case of pre-composition by a change of variables formula, but what about this case?
- I know if $\phi$ is linear and $U$ is the entire space, then the answer is yes by one of the basic properties of the Bochner integral (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral#Properties) for example).  However, it's not clear to me in general.

Comment: Let $d=D=1$ with $U = [1,\infty),$ let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure, and consider $f(x) = x^{-2/3},$ $\phi(y) = y^3.$ Then $f \in L^1_\mu(D)$ but $\phi\circ f(x) = x^{-2}$ is not integrable. In order for something like your conjecture to be true, you either need to think only about local integrability, or enforce some kind of bound on $\phi.$

Comment: I think "some kind of bound" should be a global Lipschitz condition.

Comment: @AIM_BLB: Let me check, just to make sure that I understand: are you surely interested in $\phi \circ f$ and not in $f \circ \phi$? If indeed the former, then I do not understand the condition on the essential support of $f$, because what you would need is that the *range* of $f$ be in $U$ (in order for the composition of functions to make sense). Also, if things are the way you have written them, then the answer is no: just take $U = \mathbb R$ and $\phi(x) = x + 1$, so I believe that you want $f \circ \phi$. In this case, $U$ should be a subset of $\mathbb R^d$, not $\mathbb R^D$.

Comment: So it would work in this case?